# The inputs are not showing up at all when I click on the button. If I remove the form an html then it works but I want it to work in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I know this may be a dumb question to some but I am pretty new to this and trying to learn. I have been stuck on this for days and couldn't figure it out so I came here for help. Whenever I hit the button it doesn't display my input at all. I want to make it that when the user clicks the button their input will show up in an ol list.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("todo");
let list = document.getElementById("myList");
let input = document.getElementById("add1");
let input2 = document.getElementById("add2");
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let id = 1;

button.addEventListener("click", addToDo)
list.addEventListener("click", removeEvent)


function addToDo (e) {
    let text = input.value;
    let textAdd = input2.value;
    let item = `<li class="del">
    ${text} ============= ${textAdd} <button class="del">Delete</button>`
    list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",item);
    id++; 
    document.getElementById("add1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("add2").value = "";
    

}


function removeEvent(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains("del")) {
        list.removeChild(e.target.parentElement);
        list.removeChild(list);
        
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <h1 id="name">Todo List</h1>
    <link href="project.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
   
<div id="todo">
  
  <h1>Name</h1>
<input type="text" id="add1" placeholder="Title">
<br>
<h1>Add Reminder</h1>
<input type="text" id="add2" placeholder="Notes">
  <button id="button">Submit</button>

</div>
<ol id="myList">

</ol>
    <script src="pro.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the code with the form you tried?

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me. What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something "special" about buttons within a form.

If your HTML looks like:

```
<form>
    <input placeholder="enter some text">
    <button>Click me</button>
</form>
```

Your button will **submit** the form and therefore **reset** it.

I guess you would expect the form to have some crucial properties to do so, namely 'action' and 'method' (to send the data in your inputs to some remote address - because that's the main concern of forms).

If you want your button to just be a button, use the following:

```
<form>
    <input placeholder="enter some text">
    <button type="button">Click me</button>
</form>
```

And you'll see: nothing happens.

I've created a StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gxmgt7?file=index.html) for you (just look at the HTML file). With *type="button"*, more and more inputs are added to the form. If you omit this, you can see the input is added, and immediately after it, the form resets itself (sending a GET request to '/' and refreshing everything - but that's something for another question).